# Log all committed file

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Was wondering how could I log, on the output, all the files and paths that were committed using the **pre-push** hook.
Of all the docs online I couldn't find an example on how to access the committed files list.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone looking for the same thing, I've managed to do it by fetching all the files from a commit and iterating it

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "===================="

findMe="ROOT.war/"
replaceWith="webapps/ROOT/"

for file in $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD)
do
    # echo "file: " $file
    echo ${file//$findMe/$replaceWith}
done

echo "======================================="
exit 0
```